# How to implement a search in a HTML site?

Tags: html, search

I am really wondering if i can use search for a HTML website. The pages are static. I just want the users to able to search for contents of my site. and the results shown with in my site itself. Is there anyway i can achieve this. I can use PHP on my server.
Google search can be implemented but it takes you to google's page to show the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're better off not creating your own search engine - there's loads of good ones that can be integrated into your site, which will be better than you can write yourself.
2. Google is the most popular search engine, so you might as well use that.  As an alternative to customising the html results page, you could use the [Google AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) - this does your search, and inserts the results to a specific element on your page. (DON'T forget people with javascript turned off, however...)

Answer (score 2):

I like **easy** and **fast**, so consider [**Google Custom Search**](http://www.google.com/cse/manage/create)

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities are:

- Database Extraction (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/)
- Search Indexer (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html#zend.search.lucene.overview)
- Custom Search Crawler

As for customise Google Custom Search: http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.com/2009/10/structured-custom-search.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FSyga+%28Google+Custom+Search%29

Comment: what does searchindexer and custom search crawler mean?

Comment: All your questions can be found easily via simple search ;) 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28search_engine%29/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can customize Google's result page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have php available, I would definitely suggest using that. If I were you, I would go through some PHP tutorials, and learn the basics.

[W3Schools has some great tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/).

Then, I would do some searches on building a text based database on your site, or use a clever solution [like this one](http://lipidity.com/development/forget-text-files-heres-a-php-only-database-system/). You can build a small database with metadata and store it in a text file, and it should get you going. Good luck.